# Base64 conversion in native typescript

Tags: typescript, base64

In node I can use the `Buffer` class with both `toString` overloads and the `base64Slice` method

In browser js I can use `btoa`

However in typescript I can't seem to find a native conversion, I know that I can of course import node type definitions but I want to stay as native ts, is this possible?

Essentially I want

```
let plainTextString : string = "test"
let byteArrayUint : Uint8Array = new Uint8Array([74, 65, 73, 74])
let byteArrayArr : Array<number> ​= [74, 65, 73, 74]
method(any_variable)
any_variable.method()
```

Is this possible? If there is such a method for any of the data types I will be happy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have a runtime, it doesn't have a core library, it doesn't have a standard library, it doesn't have *any* library. It arguably doesn't even have runtime semantics!

You always run a TypeScript program within some runtime (Deno, JRE, CLI, WSH, DOM, ECMAScript 2020, Node.js, etc.), and all runtime semantics, all runtime objects, functions, modules, classes, libraries, etc. come from that runtime.

> Is this possible?

No. It is not possible to do Base64 conversion in native TypeScript. It is not possible to do *anything* in native TypeScript.

It is *literally* impossible to run a TypeScript program without putting it into the context of a runtime. Any functions you use come from that runtime. You can only use the functions and functionality provided by that runtime.

Even if you implement Base64 completely by hand yourself, you still will need to rely on functions and functionality that are not part of TypeScript, such as strings and numbers (both part of ECMAScript, not TypeScript).